# Using bootstrap drop down button, getting options from database

Tags: php, sql, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

***EDIT***

So thank you to everyone so far, you have all been amazing. I found out that even though I had THOUGHT I loaded all the proper bootstrap code I apparently, did not... SO as it stands now all seems to be working! Thank you again, all so much. It was simply a combo of cluttered code and lack of proper bootstrap enabling.

I tried to look but did not find anything to resolve this issue. I am using Bootstrap for a drop down button that I am trying to populate the options in the drop down from my database. The database itself is working fine, I am able to get the data from the database itself, but I am seeming to be stuck on just making the options appear/work in the actual button itself.

Here is the button code.

```
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Select Weapon <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php 
          //Check if at least one row is found
            if($result->num_rows >0){
                //Loop through results
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                  //Display customer info
                  $output ='<li>';
                  $output .='<li>'.$row['weapon_name'].'</li>';
                  $output .='</li>';

                  //Echo output
                  echo $output;
                  }
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Here is a link to an image of what is showing up from the code above. (I am not able to post direct images quite yet.) [Button image](https://imgur.com/qDAAV22)

Any ideas? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You open a new `<ul>` tag for each element. That's not necessary.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to change that back. I will update the above message to reflect, but I changed the <ul> to <li> (and closed) and that still is not resolving, though it did change the look of the list, which I also updated the image link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
        
           </style>
           
           </head>
           <body>
           <div class="btn-group dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Select Weapon <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Q</li>
      <li>N</li>
      <li>V</li>
      <li>A</li> 
      <li>O</li>
      </ul>
      </div>

           </body>
           </html>
```

Try this---

just remove these `$output ='<ul>';
                  $output .='</ul>';` lines.

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Select Weapon <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php 
          //Check if at least one row is found
            if($result->num_rows >0){
                //Loop through results
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                  //Display customer info
                 echo '<li>';
                 echo($row['weapon_name']);
                 echo'</li>';


                  //Echo output
                  echo $output;
                  }
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I use that code, which looks like it should work, I get an error that `Notice: Undefined variable: output in C:\xampp\htdocs\apptest\weapons.php`

Comment: what is the name of this file 'weapons.php'? have you defined $output defined?

Comment: You also have to change the `.=` to `=`

Comment: @neophyte using the updated snippet from you it still is not putting the options within the drop down list. It is looking much cleaner and right, but still not right. Here is what it is looking like now [new image](http://imgur.com/e8sinf2) 
It did stop kicking back that output variable error now though.

Comment: use this ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}      to get rid of the bullets    also add class= dropdown to <div class="btn-group">

Comment: Bullets are gone, but still below the button, not within.

Comment: <div class="btn-group dropdown">-- did you try this?

Comment: Apologies, yes I did also try that, but no change.

Comment: look i have added another snippet

Comment: Correct, the standard drop down list can work, the problem is trying to implement the addition of sql database within that drop down, not just adding line items.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

//Display customer info
    $output = $row['weapon_name'];
    echo '<li>'.$output.'</li>';
    //Echo output in list

}
```

keep other code as it was.

Comment: So I tried this code and initially it gave me an error that there was an unexpected . in the code. removing the second (. ) so the code looked like this, `echo '<li>'.$output;'</li>';`

Still not within the button, but the errors are gone so the page would load without the period at the end of output.

Comment: oops. sorry! actually there is no colon after $output. echo '<li>'.$output.'</li>'; is the right way.

Comment: Gotcha. Ok I tried that as well, no errors! but no change either, still not within the button. I am truly perplexed, but greatly appreciate all the ideas/suggestions so far.

Comment: ooh! then it seems the problems in your css. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452586/display-a-ul-class-when-the-mouse-hovers-over-a-li-class-css-only may help you

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I am not sure that helps here. If I remove the database stuff/php stuff then the drop will work, that's not the problem initially. Where it becomes a problem is when I am including all the php and data to pull from the sql database I have.

Answer (score 0):

> $output ='<li>';   //// Remove this line
>                     $output .='<li>'.$row['weapon_name'].'</li>';
>                     $output .='</li>'; //remove this line also  
>                     //Echo output
>                     echo $output;

Hope it will work .

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the re-affirmed bootstrap code that seemed to have, while clearing my css stuff (minor), fixed the button to work and properly show the database. Thank you all.